# having to press key twice for EventListener (javascript)

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm doing some DOM manipulation in javascript (I know there's other faster ways out there I'm just trying to learn the old ways first!)

I created this EventListener:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", delitem);
```

..and the following function:

```
function delitem(evt) {
if (evt.keyCode == 46) {
ul.removeChild(ul.lastChild);
  }
}
```

Hoping that when i press the 'delete' key anywhere on the webpage, the last item in the list will be deleted. However, I have to press the 'delete' key twice for it to work and I have no idea why it's happening?

If I add a new item to the list, then I can press 'delete' once to remove it.. but for existing items it has to be pressed twice. 
Appreciate your help.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="list-group "> 
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Notebook</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Peas</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Spinach</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Rice</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Birthday Cake</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Candles</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is `ul` ? ...

Comment: Try debugging it urself by using debugger or Console log inside ur delete item functio.

Comment: @gurpreet what should debugging reveal here?

Comment: @JonasWilms debugging would reveal the same thing as you pointed in your answer. One can always check what their functions are returning in this case lastChild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lastChild` returns the last node inside the element, and that node is a textnode as you got a newline at the end of the line which is interpreted as text:

```
 </li>\n</ul>
```

As you want to get the last element and not the last node, you could use `lastElementChild` instead or just remove the line break:

```
 </li></ul>
```

Comment: This behaviour is described in the german version of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild#Beispiel), this should definetly be taken over in the english version too...

Comment: Please link to the English version of documentation since this is primarily an English-based site.

Comment: `lastElementChild` certainly works, but see this http://jsfiddle.net/8yLrknpj/ there is no `\n`

Answer (score 2):

here is the complete code, it should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="list-group "> 
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Notebook</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Peas</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Spinach</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Rice</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Birthday Cake</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info ">Candles</li>
</ul>
<script>
document.addEventListener("keydown", delitem);
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
function delitem(evt) {
if (evt.keyCode == 46 && ul.children.length ) {
ul.removeChild(ul.lastChild);
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lastElementChild` or query for the last element.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKPgjg

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const ul = document.querySelector('.list-group');

  document.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {
    if (ev.keyCode === 8) {
      // query for the last li element to avoid text nodes
      const lastChild = ul.querySelector(':last-child');

      if (lastChild) {
        ul.removeChild(lastChild);        
      }

      // alternatively you could use this
      //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild
      // ul.removeChild(ul.lastElementChild);
    }
  });
});
```